# Constraints with better performence

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

In my model, client_id must be one per product. So I want to make a constraint for this situation.

```py
class ClientSystemCode(models.Model):
    _name = 'client.system.code'
    _description = 'Client System Code'

    client_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Client')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', 'Product')
    client_sys_code = fields.Char('Client system code')
```

in product.template model my constraints look like this.

```py
@api.constrains('client_system_code_ids')
    def _client_system_code_constraint(self):
        duplicates = []
        for line in self.client_system_code_ids:
            if line.client_id.id not in duplicates:
                duplicates.append(line.client_id.id)
            else:
                raise ValidationError(_("Product can't have more than one client code with same client"))
```

it is ok as it triggered from product form view and there always be not that much lines. But constraint in client.system.code should be better performance wise because there can be thousands of lines. So is there any kind of better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get it done easily using an sql constraint like:

```
class ClientSystemCode(models.Model):
    _name = 'client.system.code'

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('client_product_unique', 'unique (client_id, product_id)', 'Product can't have more than one client code with same client'),
    ]
```

Comment: 2018-09-10 17:07:18,771 31297 INFO 09071 openerp.sql_db: bad query: ALTER TABLE "client_system_code" ADD CONSTRAINT "client_system_code_def_client_product_unique" unique (client_id, product_id)
2018-09-10 17:07:18,771 31297 WARNING 09071 openerp.models.schema: Table 'client_system_code': unable to add 'unique (client_id, product_id)' constraint !
 If you want to have it, you should update the records and execute manually:
ALTER TABLE "client_system_code" ADD CONSTRAINT "client_system_code_def_client_product_unique" unique (client_id, product_id). i did table alter but not working

Comment: Did your manual alter table to add the constraint works? Seems that you already have non unique combination of client_id and product_id values in the client_system_code table

Comment: Good to know. Happy to help